# My service is not recognizing the file names contained in directory with Java 8

Tags: file, java-8, readfile

I am creating a service and I am using java 8, I want to retrieve the file names as a list, those are in a folder into resources/ and when I am running locally is working but when I deployed my application into DEV/QA environment is getting empty, is not recognizing those files, and I have some considerations:

1. In the full path, in one folder is hidden folder (.cache), that
   could affect it?, this is the path:
   file:/newarch/apps/project-1/servers/project-service-1/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/55/data/cache/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_723/.cache/project-service-ser.jar!/services
2. I gave rights on the folder as reader and writer.

This is the structure of the folder that I wanna retrieve the names:

```
resources/
    services/
        service-host1.js
        service-host2.js
        service-host3.js
        service-host4.js
```

This is my code to read:

```
public List<String> getFilesFromDirectory(String dirName) throws IOException {
        dirName = dirName + "/";
        try (Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.list(Paths.get(dirName))) {
            return pathStream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .map(Path::getFileName)
                    .map(Path::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

this is the way how I am getting the full path:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("service").getPath()
```

Could you give any advice what could be the problem?

Comment: There is no point in adding a `"/"` to the filename. But anyway, the `!/` suggests that you want to access an entry in a jar file, but that doesn’t work with a `file:` URI. You’d have to use a `jar:` URI. Further, you have to use the [`Paths.get(URI)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)) method. The `get(String, String...)` method expects a path of the default filesystem, not a URI.

Comment: In other words, when you have a `URL`, like the one returned by `getResource("service")`, don’t extract a part of it and use it out of context. You can convert a URL to a URI via [`.toURI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#toURI()), but it’s possible that you have to create a filesystem for the jar file first, before you can use `Paths.get(URI)`.